# MongoDB collStats.size compared to collection.totalSize

Tags: mongodb, memory, disk-space

I have a collection which has the following dimensions:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.myCollection.totalSize()
2188206080

rs0:PRIMARY> db.myCollection.stats()
{
    "size" : 5899660704,
    "avgObjSize" : 640710,
    "storageSize" : 2187829248,
```

According to the mongo docs:

> db.collection.totalSize()
>   The total size in bytes of the data in the collection plus the size of every indexes on the collection

which to me, means the collection is 2.18Gb in size (including the indexes).

The docs also state:

> collStats.size()
>   The total size in memory of all records in a collection

So what I dont understand is why size = 5899660704 (5.9Gb) i.e. significantly bigger than totalSize?

Comment: `size` denotes the _uncompressed_ size, whereas `totalSize()`returns the total size of the compressed data files (data + headers)